# XAML how can i use image outside of main method?

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio

I placed a image without a source, i wanted the source of image to change between if states like this example:

XAML:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GjAnd.png)

And here is my c# code:

```
 public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        var startTimeSpan = TimeSpan.Zero; //Start Counting from 0
        var periodTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10); //Every 10 minutes
        var timer = new System.Threading.Timer((e) =>
        {
            EA(); //loads the method every 10 minute

        }, null, startTimeSpan, periodTimeSpan);
    }

    public static void EA()
    {

        var lines = File.ReadAllLines("EscolaDasArmas.txt"); //reads ip cameras txt
        int timeout = 0; //Count how many timeout
        int success = 0; //Count how many success
        for (int i = 0; i < lines.Length; i++) //for each line in txt 
        {
            Ping ping = new Ping();
            PingReply reply = ping.Send(lines[i]); //ping each camera
            if (reply.Status == IPStatus.Success)
            {
                success++; //Increments success cameras
            }

            else if (reply.Status == IPStatus.TimedOut)
            {
                timeout++; //Increments for each timeout camera
            }

        }
        if (success > timeout)
        {
            PingStatusGreen();
            //loads green image
        }

        else
        {
            PingStatusRed();
            //loads red image
        }
    }

    public static void PingStatusGreen()
    {
        BitmapImage green = new BitmapImage(new Uri("/CameraControl;component/status/green.png", UriKind.Relative)); 

    }

    public static void PingStatusRed()
    {
        BitmapImage red = new BitmapImage(new Uri("/CameraControl;component/status/red.png", UriKind.Relative));
    }
}
```

}

My problem is that i can only work with the image inside the main method, outside it doesn't recognize it, i am trying to do:

eaMafra.Source = green;
eaMafra.Source = red;

any help welcome.

Comment: Make green and red class members, like `private readonly BitmapImage green;` and initialize them only once. Then later only assign `eaMafra.Source = green;` and similarly red. Besides that, the image URIs are wrong. The image files appear to be assembly resource files (i.e. with Build Action `Resource`). In code behind you have to access them by full Pack URIs like `new BitmapImage(new Uri("pack://application:,,,/CameraControl;component/status/green.png"));` without UriKind.

Comment: One more note, if you are going to modify UI elements from a timer callback, use the DispatcherTimer class. Its Tick handler is already invoked in the UI thread.

Comment: Remove the `static` keyword from the `EA` and `PingStatusXxx` methods, you'll get access to `eaMafra` (assuming that's the name of your control set from XAML).

Comment: System.Threading.Timer executes on the ThreadPool thread. That isn't the UI thread and any UI elements have thread affinity. Use DispatcherTimer instead. There may be some other problems as well.